# google maps api center on my location with a button

Tags: html, google-maps, button, geolocation

Everything is working but I would really like for the last button (GPS) (sorry can't post image)
to center the map on the user location instead of just refreshing the map like I currently have it set up to do.

An example of how this would work is for the user to have the webpage open and scroll around the map, possibly changing to satellite view, then be able to click the above button (or any button for that matter) and have the map pan back to their location.  Not sure if this is even possible, but I can't seem to figure it out on my own.  Any help is very much appreciated.  Here is the link to my Frankenstein map.  http://deepfrogphoto.com/Brett-Pelletier-Photography/Links/maps/wasatch-ski-map-mobile.htm

```
var map, GeoMarker;      

    function toggleLayer(this_layer){
  if(this_layer.getMap()) {
    this_layer.setMap(null)
  } else {
    this_layer.setMap(map);}}

      function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 20,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.563855, -111.675426),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
    GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
      map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
      map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
      alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
    });

    GeoMarker.setMap(map);

     trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(map); 

    layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "skilines",
    from: "1R5pCEyNN74N8Dt9MkfNXA6A9D1HbQESzOR1fYFa7",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});   

layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "resorts",
    from: "19iu58FDFcBIZZ-wU1iZcf89AI5ABDJ7YTv355su5",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});      

 layer3 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "summerhiking",
    from: "1t1XNnG7J7Zu1p5mIUpm6qIGVYwzhkCgPy_je0IKr",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});       

layer4 = new google.maps.KmlLayer('URL-to-KML.kml',
              {
                  suppressInfoWindows: false,
                  map: map,
                  preserveViewport: true
              });        
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');}

//]]>
</script>

<title>Wasatch Map by deepfrogphoto</title>
</head>

<body>
<b>Wasatch Map by deepfrogphoto -</b>

<form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Center Map on My Location</button>

</form>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post the (relevant) code in your question.  Once you page is "fixed", your question will no longer have context.

Comment: do you know the co-ordinates or are you wanting it to automatically detect any users location?

Comment: sorry, like i said very much a rookie here.  i'm not sure what the relevant code is... it's all relevant in my mind because one little bit wrong messes it all up.  i thought people could look at my page link, grab the code, and help me with my question the way i have it posted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a button with onclick event listener

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Center</button>
```

then create the myFunction to center the map to user position

```
function myFunction(){
      Map.panTo(UserCords);//UserCords = user current latitude, longitude. I suppose you have them!!!
}
```

**EDIT**

```
function myFunction(){
     if (navigator.geolocation){
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition,showError);
     }
     else{
          alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
     }
 }

function getPosition(position)
  { 
      UserLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
      UserLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
      showPosition(UserLatitude, UserLongitude);
  }

function showPosition(userLatitude, userLongitude){
        lat= userLatitude;
        lon= userLongitude;
        latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        YourMap.panTo(latlon);
}

function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Location information is unavailable.")
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("The request to get user location timed out.")
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      alert("An unknown error occurred.")
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks this seems to be what i need, but i don't know what you mean by 'i suppose you have them'  ... when the my page loads i have the geolocation (blue dot) working, but not sure about these UserCords...  i assume 'i have them' or it wouldn't work, but not sure about any of this....

Comment: does it work for you? I meant that e.x UserCords = new google.maps.LatLng(40.563855, -111.675426)

Comment: not yet... i added the button code... and can see that.. and added the function code, but it's not working for me.... it could be where i put it, or the words UserCords.. maybe i don't have them.. or they are called something else?

Comment: check my edit and copy paste the code and change YourMap with your map name (as i see in you source code the name of your map is "map"). So change Yourmap with map and it must play!!

Comment: wow i really appreciate your help with this.. though i still can't get it to work.  i've tried the adding the function code edit above to my code and i'm not getting an error like i was before, but it still isn't working for me.. the button isn't doing anything...  is it working for you??  can you please give me a complete example so i don't question where to add your code.